# Problem Dynamically Drawing to Tkinter Canvas Object

Tags: python, tkinter-canvas

***One question***: How do you dynamically draw to a Tkinter Canvas object from a button click?

This topic was posted originally by user339860 (see 1) as a two part question,  but the second portion of the question has not yet been addressed. I'm experiencing the same problem, specifically **I cannot draw to a Canvas object from a button event**. Getting this question answered will help two people, myself and user339860; please take a look.

The application creates two frames positioned left and right, the second frame contains the Canvas object. I have a button in the first frame bound to a function/method named *drawRectangle*. The application runs fine, **it even draws a rectangle in the Canvas object using the *create_rectangle* method**, until you click the button. When you click the button you get a message with the following;

> tkinter_app_27Nov2010.py", line 25, in drawRectangle
> self.myCan.create_rectangle(64,64,110,110,fill='blue')
> AttributeError: **'NoneType' object has no attribute 'create_rectangle'**

I thought it might have something to do with the scope of the Canvas object, so I created a *class level* variable set to *None*, but that didn't fix the issue. I thought about the Canvas *display list* (see 2), but the Tk manual pages don't reflect a method of adding a new object that I could find.

### CODE:

---

```
# tkinter_app_27Nov2010.py
from Tkinter import *
class Application(Frame):
myCan = None
def createWidgets(self):
    uiFrame = Frame(self,width=300,height=30)
    uiFrame.configure(background='#e0e0e0')
    uiFrame.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=N+S)

    outputFrame = Frame(self,width=300,height=300,background='#C0C0C0')
    outputFrame.grid(row=0,column=1)

    newBtn = Button(uiFrame,text="testing",command=self.drawRectangle)
    newBtn.grid(row=0,column=0)
    fillLbl = Label(uiFrame,text='-').grid(row=1,sticky=N+S)
    
    newLBL = Label(outputFrame,text="another testing",background='#C0C0C0')
    newLBL.grid(row=0)

    myCan = Canvas(outputFrame,width=300,height=300,borderwidth=1,relief='sunken')
    myCan.grid(row=1)
    myCan.create_rectangle(34,34,50,50,fill='red')

def drawRectangle(self):
    self.myCan.create_rectangle(64,64,110,110,fill='blue')
    
def __init__(self,master):
    Frame.__init__(self,master)
    self.pack()
    self.createWidgets()
```

root = Tk()
myApp = Application(master=root)
root.title("Tkinter Testing!")
myApp.mainloop()

---

There has to be a way to get a handle on the "damage/repair display model" (see 3) the Tkinter Canvas object uses to update itself. Please help!

### References:

1. stackoverflow.com/questions/2824041/dynamically-add-items-to-tkinter-canvas
2. [www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M16](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M16)
3. effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#performance-issues

Comment: The second part of question you reference as (1) _was_ answered. Both parts of that question were caused by the same line of code. And in that case, the problem is not the same problem you are having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Python problem, not a `tkinter` one. You have defined local variables inside `createWidgets`, but you haven't set them as instance attributes. You need to use `self.foo` for that:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def __init__(self):
...             bar = "baz"
...
>>> class Bar:
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.bar = "baz"
...
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.bar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: Foo instance has no attribute 'bar'
>>> bar = Bar()
>>> bar.bar
'baz'
```

Notice that you are indeed correct: the problem is to do with the scope of the `Canvas`. Or more precisely, with the scope of the `myCan` variable. If you hadn't defined the class variable `myCan`, the lookup `self.myCan` would have raised a revealing `AttributeError`.

Comment: Thank you, katrielalex! Your insight, along with Wooee, resolved the issue perfectly! I greatly appreciate your provided example so that I can more clearly see the proper application of instance attributes. Outstanding! Thanks again.

Comment: @code: No problem! A general rule of thumb is that Python likes local variables, and everything will be local to its scope unless it has some reason not to be (`global`, `nonlocal`, ...).

Answer (score 1):

There is no object "self.myCan".  You have to create it as a canvas object or whatever before you can use it.  You may also have to call update_idletasks() depending on what you do.

Comment: Thank you, Wooee! Both you and katrielalex are right! Using self properly (self.myCan) is all that was needed to solve the issue. Thank you for your time in reviewing and posting your insight on this.